# What is the name of this theorem (analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Please Can you remind me with the name of this theorem and its reference book

Assume that $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is continuous and integrable function over $\mathbb{R}$ then we've

$$\lim_{t \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds=f(0)$$

Thank you.

Comment: Even if $f$ is integrable, in the Riemann sense, that is false. For example consider $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=1$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Assuming certain continuous hypothesis, this is not more that the fundamental theorem of calculus or, better said, a variation of it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for some variation of the Mean Value Theorem for Integration:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Actually you can prove it directly from the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (cf: Spivak-Calculus p.268).

Let $F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds$. Then for $f$ continuous at $0$ (and $f$ integrable in some $[a,b]$ with $a<0<b$), you get that $F'(0)=f(0)$ and since $F'(0)=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{F(t)}{t}$ you get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks but if we assume what you said true can you show me the relationship between the MVT and $$\lim_{t \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds=f(0)$$

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I agree this should be the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.